# BitPay API: How to create an Invoice with more than one Item?

Tags: php, api

There is an example [here](https://github.com/bitpay/php-bitpay-client/blob/master/examples/tutorial/004.php) on how to create an invoice with only one item, but how to add more? I've tried to create $item twice and add it to $invoice, but with no success. The API does not accept it.

An excerpt from the example above:

```
/**
 * Code that makes the invoice
 */
$invoice = new \Bitpay\Invoice();
$item    = new \Bitpay\Item();
$item
    ->setCode('skuNumber')
    ->setDescription('General Description of Item')
    ->setPrice('1.99');
$invoice->setCurrency(new \Bitpay\Currency('USD'));
$client = $bitpay->get('client');
$client->setToken($token);

$client->createInvoice($invoice);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On labs.bitpay.com Rich Morgans answered my questions how to programmatically create bills, which can contain more than one item. It works slightliy different. Please read the [docs](https://bitpay.com/api#resource-Bills). you will find [the createRefund snippet](https://labs.bitpay.com/t/php-bitpay-client-how-to-create-a-bill/469/2) useful. You will have to modify Client.php and add the following code to the Client class.

```
public function createBill(\Bitpay\Bill $bill)
{
    $request = $this->createNewRequest();

    $request->setMethod(Request::METHOD_POST);
    $request->setPath('bills');

    $body = array(
        'items' => array(array('description' => 'somecooldescription', 'price' => 1.45, 'quantity' => 5)),
        'guid'  => Util::guid(),
        'nonce' => Util::nonce(),
        'token' => '7U24AhTLM3A36iN4bUsEvcEcxB8UeEPSn7ghEYuCbkoc',
    );

    $request->setBody(json_encode($body));

    $this->addIdentityHeader($request);
    $this->addSignatureHeader($request);

    $this->request  = $request;
    $this->response = $this->sendRequest($request);

    $response = json_decode($this->response->getBody(), true);

    return array('request' => json_encode($body), 'response' => $this->response->getBody());
}
```

You call it like this

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$bitpay = new \Bitpay\Bitpay(
    array(
          'bitpay' => array(
          'network'     => 'testnet',
          'public_key'  => '/tmp/public.key',
          'private_key' => '/tmp/private.key',
          'key_storage' => 'Bitpay\Storage\FilesystemStorage',
           )
        )
    );

$client = $bitpay->get('client');
$tokens = $client->getTokens();

$client->setAdapter(new \Bitpay\Client\Adapter\CurlAdapter());

$bill = new \Bitpay\Bill;
$info = $client->createBill($bill);

print_r($info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoices in bitpay are for fixed priced invoices. If you want to have multiple items you are going to want to use a bill. I suggest reading up on their rest api a little more:

https://bitpay.com/api

Comment: I use the official PHP API lib hosted on [Github](https://github.com/bitpay/php-bitpay-client). I found a Bill class but examples or documents on how to use it are not there. Do you have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

So with Invoice items it's different than your local invoice. There is a parameter named 'posData' that you can use as pass-through for your local invoice. The invoice for Bitpay should reflect that it is a 3rd party invoice. So your line item should say

`"Invoice 123123 for {{your company name}}" "$35.00"`

or something more specific

`"{{company}} service for July" "$35.00"`

You should be tracking your own invoices outside of Bitpay. Do your calculations and totals make a relevant description then send it to Bitpay.